# Handling files serverside with remix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I am trying to upload image files to a CDN using a form. Im able to get it to work using the fetch API, however I don't want to do it client side. The following seems like the right way of doing so but, it doesn't seem to work.

```
export async function action({request}: ActionArgs) {
    const body = await request.formData();

    await fetch(`${API}/${body.get("fileName")}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: body.get("file"),
        headers: {}
    }).then((response) => response.json());

    return json({});
}

export default function UploadImage() {
    const fetcher = useFetcher();
    
    const handleChange = async (e: any) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const fileData = new FormData();

        fileData.append('file', file);
        fileData.append('fileName', file.name);

        fetcher.submit(
            fileData,
            { method: 'POST' }
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
        </>
    );
}
```

I know I'm suppose to use [unstableMultipartFormData](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/utils/parse-multipart-form-data#uploadhandler)
but the documentation doesn't explain how to write the upload handler for cases where you would want to upload the file to a CDN. Examples and tutorials that I have found seem outdated, using older versions that no longer work. And I'm not even sure what parameters or behaviour the uploadHandler expects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Remix Example should show you the process.

https://github.com/remix-run/examples/tree/main/file-and-s3-upload

Replace the S3 upload handler with your own.

```js
// utils/s3.server.ts

export const s3UploadHandler: UploadHandler = async ({
  name, // name is the `<input type="file" name="img">` so make sure you set that
  filename,
  data, // data is the file data as `AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>`
}) => {
  
  if (name !== "img") {
    return undefined;
  }
  const uploadedFileLocation = await uploadStreamToS3(data, filename!);
  return uploadedFileLocation;
};
```

https://github.com/remix-run/examples/blob/ba029da81459d1445d4756af86e573f507eeb43d/file-and-s3-upload/app/utils/s3.server.ts#L40-L50

Here are the Remix types

```js
export type UploadHandlerPart = {
  name: string;
  filename?: string;
  contentType: string;
  data: AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>;
};

export type UploadHandler = (
  part: UploadHandlerPart
) => Promise<File | string | null | undefined>;
```

https://github.com/remix-run/remix/blob/e35569ed5334c0c00ea5ecfdd881ff9e2dfb290b/packages/remix-server-runtime/formData.ts#L4C1-L14C1

Comment: Im receiving a Payload too large error. I'm beginning to question if this is even the right method for handling files with remix. I can just post the file to an express server and handle it from there

Comment: I was able to get it to work with a few files that were under a MB, anything larger throws PayloadTooLargeError

Comment: If I remove the S3 handler and default to the memory handler, it fails when the payload > 3MB (default, which can be overridden). Are you using Remix App Server or another adapter?

Comment: running on shopify's oxygen platform. reading through their docs I see that theres limitations that can't be raised. It suggests using streams, so Ill look into that

Comment: I'll try testing this, but It should be possible to use the fetch API to call an action or loader in remix, correct? If so then I should be able to stream the data to an action. I might be misunderstanding the point of useFetcher, but I get the sense that its an easy way of handling fetches but a bit simplified in terms of what it does.